# Zoom and perform onTouch event in FrameLayout

Tags: android

I Have a Frame Layout having 4 images in it image1,image2,image3,image4. I am able to zoom/pinch this Frame layout.I am able to perform on touch event for images by using X,Y position without zoom.

Question : How to achieve images on touch functionality individually after zoom.

```
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements caleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

      private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
      }

      private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
      private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
      private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 4.0f;

      private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
      private float scale = 1.0f;
      private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

      // Where the finger first  touches the screen
      private float startX = 0f;
      private float startY = 0f;

      // How much to translate the canvas
      private float dx = 0f;
      private float dy = 0f;
      private float prevDx = 0f;
      private float prevDy = 0f;

      public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
      }

      public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
      }

      public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
      }

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void init(final Context context) {
        final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

              com.example.target.ZoomLayout test=(com.example.target.ZoomLayout) view;
              System.out.println( "iddd : "+test.getId());
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
                if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                  mode = Mode.DRAG;
                  startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                  startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                }
                FrameLayout vv=(FrameLayout) child();
                System.out.println("count= "+vv.getChildCount());
                int count=vv.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 1; i <count; i++) {
                    float startx,starty,endx,endy;
                     ImageView iv=(ImageView) vv.getChildAt(i);
                        startx=iv.getX()+startX;
                        starty=iv.getY()+startY;
                        endx=iv.getX()+iv.getWidth();
                        endy=iv.getY()+iv.getHeight();

                     if(motionEvent.getX()>(  startx ) && motionEvent.getX()<(endx ) && motionEvent.getY()>(( starty )+getStatusBarHeight() ) && motionEvent.getY()<(( endy)+getStatusBarHeight()))


                     {
                          System.out.println("count= "+iv.getId());
                         Toast.makeText(context, "i = "+i, 3000).show();
                     }
                }

                break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                  dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                  dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
                }
                break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = Mode.DRAG;
                break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i(TAG, "UP");
                mode = Mode.NONE;
                prevDx = dx;
                prevDy = dy;
                break;
            }
            scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

            if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
              getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
              float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
              float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale))/ 2 * scale;
              dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
              dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
              Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                + ", max " + maxDx);
              applyScaleAndTranslation();
            }

            return true;
          }
        });
      }

      // ScaleGestureDetector

      @Override
      public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);
        if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
          scale *= scaleFactor;
          scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
          lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        } else {
          lastScaleFactor = 0;
        }
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
      }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(scale);
        child().setScaleY(scale);
        child().setTranslationX(dx);
        child().setTranslationY(dy);
      }

      private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
      }
      public float getStatusBarHeight() {
            float result = 0;
            float resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
              if (resourceId > 0) {
                  result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize((int) resourceId);
              }

              return result;
            }
    }





public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    com.example.target.ZoomLayout zoomerframe;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        zoomerframe=(com.example.target.ZoomLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoomerframe);
        ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    FrameLayout frame=new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setLayoutParams(params);

        iv.setLayoutParams(params);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.notifications_bg);
        frame.addView(iv);
        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                200,
                200);


        params.leftMargin = (int) 100;
        params.topMargin = (int) 100;
        ImageView iv2=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv2.setLayoutParams(params);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.trnspr);

        frame.addView(iv2);

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                50,
                50);


        params.leftMargin = (int) 500;
        params.topMargin = (int) 500;
        ImageView iv3=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv3.setLayoutParams(params);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.trnspr);

        frame.addView(iv3);
        zoomerframe.addView(frame);


    }



}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.target.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <com.example.target.ZoomLayout 

          android:id="@+id/zoomerframe"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        ></com.example.target.ZoomLayout >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you saying that after zooming, the onTouchListeners on individual images are not getting triggered on touch?

Comment: How did you implement the pinch zoom?

Comment: yes after zooming,the ontouch event is not triggering,it is triggering only on total  framelayout